# ESLint no-multiple-empty-lines rule like but only inside object properties scope

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a way to prevent line breaks only inside object properties scope? Let me give you guys more context, I have the **no-multiple-empty-lines** configured like the below:

```
"no-multiple-empty-lines": [
    "error",
    {
        "max": 1
    }
]
```

Which means I can separate logical sections of code with the a single line (two `\n`):

```
var foo = 5;

var bar = 3;
```

Sadly it's also possible to line break object properties, something I'm trying to avoid:

```
const a = {
  b: 0,
  
  c: 2
}
```

So, again, here's my question: Is there a way to prevent that?